# How to run Command as a different user with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, dns

I'm trying to make a script that changes the HostnameAlias for a given dns record.

But only certain users have access to editing these records, for example `ADMIN` can edit it but `CURRENTUSER` cannot.

Currently I have this piece of code:

```
param(
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
    $Credential = $(Get-Credential)
)
$Command = "Set-DnsServerResourceRecord -NewInputObject $($NewObject) -OldInputObject $($OldObject) -ZoneName $($ZoneName)"
Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -NoNewWindow -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList $Command
```

But i just keep getting `Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The user name or password is incorrect` even though I am absolutely sure they are indeed correct.

What am I doing wrong here.

Ps, I have looked at all the related questions, none seem to answer my question.

Comment: Does the user you are entering have rights to start a process on the host you are running this script on? From what I am seeing, the `start-process` is already throwing the error.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the error even though I'm typing the credentials of my current user(which has rights to edit the dns record I'm testing on currently).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a mistake on my part, forgot to specify domain before username when entering credentials.

Can solve it like this `Get-Credential Domain\`

Answer (score 0):

You can call **System.Management.Automation.PSCredential** object to specify any credentials you want and run with it in any process

```bsh
$User = 'yourdomain\youruser'
$Password = 'yourpassword'

$Secure_Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $Secure_Password)


$Command = "Set-DnsServerResourceRecord -NewInputObject $($NewObject) -OldInputObject $($OldObject) -ZoneName $($ZoneName)"
Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -NoNewWindow -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList $Command
```

Comment: Yes i know. Edited question to better reflect my actual code.
I'm using Get-Credential instead to prompt the user for username and password. Either way, I should have a propert Credentials object right?

Comment: Did you try to put the user input into double quotes ? Im not sure about the second question im going to ask but , does get-credential automatically converts the password into secure string ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
#Get User credential
$Credential = Get-Credential Domain\UserNameYouWant

#Use System.Diagnostics to start the process as User
$ProcessInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
#With FileName we're basically telling powershell to run another powershell process
$ProcessInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"
#CreateNoWindow helps avoiding a second window to appear whilst the process runs
$ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
#Note the line below contains the Working Directory where the script will start from
$ProcessInfo.WorkingDirectory = $env:windir
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true 
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true 
$ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
#The line below is basically the command you want to run and it's passed as text, as an argument
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = "The command you want"
#The next 3 lines are the credential for User as you can see, we can't just pass $Credential
$ProcessInfo.Username = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().username
$ProcessInfo.Domain = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Domain
$ProcessInfo.Password = $Credential.Password
#Finally start the process and wait for it to finish
$Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process 
$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo 
$Process.Start() | Out-Null 
$Process.WaitForExit() 
#Grab the output
$GetProcessResult = $Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
# Print the Job results
$GetProcessResult
```